# Multiple Inputs / Outputs for Dataset class in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I've created a Dataset class for PyTorch that can read/generate batches for problems with `Nin` images as inputs and `Nout` images as outputs. Now I have to pass this class to the DataLoader, but I don't know how to format such inputs / outputs in order to be supported by the DataLoader. For example I don't think it has to be `BatchSize x Nin x Channels x Height x Width` because it could not support images with different channels (or dimensions in general).

Comment: The question is also how your network is supposed to process these images in the end? Can you maybe share some insights on how differently shaped images would (together) make for a valid predicitions?

Comment: The network would just do different number of convolution before to merge/concateneate the features. I don't know how to format and pass such inputs (even of identical dimensions) to the DataLoader

Comment: How do you determine what number of convolutions to perform before you are deciding to "exit the network"? And how is that supposed to have reproducible results across multiple images?

Comment: That's not really the problem, it was just an example. If it simplifies things, just suppose images have the same dimensions.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad. Another (hopefully more related) question, though: Do you want to re-use the same image in different batches, or is each image used exactly in one batch during each epoch? And wouldn't the DataLoader only care about `Nin` for the loading part?

Comment: Each image would be loaded only once per epoch, and the DataLoader has to mange both the inputs and the outputs.